# Create categorical variables from continuous variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case, data-transform

This is my dataset with three columns.

```
  ID     Flag    Z
  121    1       54.027
  122    1       41.7267
  121    2       26.006
  645    1       86.612
  217    1       95.831
  217    2        6.616
```

I like to create a fourth column which is a categorical variable with three levels based on the values in Z and Flag.

```
If the Flag = 2 then NewCol = "Flag2"
If the Flag = 1 and value of Z is above or equal to the median of Z then NewCol = "GT EQ Median"
If the Flag = 1 and value of Z is below the median of Z then NewCol = "LT Median"
```

The median of Z is estimated only for Z values where Flag=1, in this case `median(c(54.027, 41.7267, 86.612, 95.831))`~  70.32. So if Flag = 1 and Z >= 54.027 then NewCol = "GT EQ Median", if Flag = 1 and Z < 54.027 then NewCol = "LT Median"

```
  ID     Flag    Z        NewCol
  121    1       54.027   LT Median
  122    1       41.7267  LT Median
  121    2       26.006   Flag2
  645    1       86.612   GT EQ Median
  217    1       95.831   GT EQ Median
  217    2        6.616   Flag2
```

I tried this with `case_when` function but I was not sure how to include the logic to check for median of Z when Flag=1. Any suggestion here is much appreciated. Thanks.

---------- question updated based on Benson and Darren's suggestion.

Comment: @DarrenTsai, I missed the c()..as benson pointed out, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `dplyr` package, you can specify per group calculation using `group_by()`, and specify multiple condition with **and** `&`.

Also, the input for `median()` should be a vector of numeric values, therefore you should wrap your numbers with `c()`. Otherwise, it would return the first number as the median, which is clearly incorrect.

```r
median(c(54.027, 41.7, 86.6, 95.8))
[1] 70.3135
```

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Flag) %>% 
  mutate(newCol = case_when(Flag == 2 ~ "Flag2",
                            Flag == 1 & Z >= median(Z) ~ "GT EQ Median",
                            Flag == 1 & Z < median(Z) ~ "LT Median")) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 4
     ID  Flag     Z newCol      
  <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>       
1   121     1 54.0  LT Median   
2   122     1 41.7  LT Median   
3   121     2 26.0  Flag2       
4   645     1 86.6  GT EQ Median
5   217     1 95.8  GT EQ Median
6   217     2  6.62 Flag2
```